# On click on iframe redirect to other page

Tags: javascript, php

I am having a PHP page with the image in the Iframe when I click on the image in iframe how can my page redirect to another page...
My Iframe code is coming from javascript...

```html
<a href="brandtalk.php" style="display:block">
<iframe id="iframe'  + kpiName + rand  +'" class="widget-iframe" style="overflow:hidden;height:256px;" src="./jss/'+ kpiName.toLowerCase() + '.php?keyword=iphone&location=New+York&language=en&limit=100"></iframe></a>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You shouldn't use <script> </script> around html code

Comment: Is iframe URL a cross domain url?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, but from what I understand is that you want to redirect the whole page. So you can use this JavaScript code: `window.top.location.href = 'here write the URL you want to redirect the page to'`

Comment: I have my html code in Js file. I am Including a graph data from javascript in IFrame for displaying.Like I have so many graphs for displaying. So when I click on particular graph my page must be redirected to other php page.